# Crystal reports v12 doesnt show the report after hosting

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, crystal-reports-2008

I am working on a project in ASP.net 3.5 (with VB script) and Crystal Reports 2008 (V12). It works fine when I run my solution in visual studio(2008) but after publishing it to local IIS(7) it doesnt show the report in the report viewer. I don't see any error either.

I have placed the 'aspnet_client' folder under wwwroot folder that contains crystal report related files.

I had used crystal report 10.5 previously but then I had converted it to V12 as my host doent't support old versions.
Your support in this regard would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced this issue and successfully managed to get the reports running. I am using Visual Studio 2005 but I published my project on a local server with Windows 2008 Server R2 Enterprise.

I fixed the issue by changing the Application Pool settings of IIS 7. I changed it to Classic ASP.NET for .NET 2.0 Framework. I guess you may not require this setting, but I am not sure.

Secondly, when you open your report in Visual Studio 2005, check that you are using OLE DB Provider for SQL Server and not SQL Native Client, just in case you are using SQL Server database.

Which OS you are using? I hope you are not using Windows XP. Windows XP has issues with the **Integrated Security** thing mentioned in your Connection String.